# How to append jsonp object to html with callback function

Tags: jquery, json, callback, append, jsonp

I have web service that return me json object (jsonp with callback) and I need to loop though it and display the results to my Html page.
the results I got looks likes this:

```
CBGroupSale({
"GroupSales": [{
    "PICTURE": "0F5340E1-A25D-157B-99D2BF64DCF1F05F.jpg",
    "DISPRECENT": 7.0,
    "PRICE": 1640,
    "CLASS": 5,
    "GROUPLEFT": 5,
    "HOTELNAME": "hotel 1"
}, {
    "PICTURE": "9FE127E7-9668-1214-28251C533DD7F657.jpg",
    "DISPRECENT": 25.0,
    "PRICE": 2800,
    "CLASS": 4,
    "GROUPLEFT": 10,
    "HOTELNAME": "hotel 2"
}, {
    "PICTURE": "0F5340E1-A25D-157B-99D2BF64DCF1F05F.jpg",
    "DISPRECENT": 7.0,
    "PRICE": 2680,
    "CLASS": 5,
    "GROUPLEFT": 8,
    "HOTELNAME": "hotel 3"
}]
```

})

I wants to display it in Html `<li>` tags.
any help???

Answer (score 1):

Use `.ajax()` just set it to `JSONP`

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
       console.dir(json.sites);
    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
    }
});

})(jQuery);
```

From: http://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/

Comment: Hello Zee Tee thanks for the quick answer
i use it and i get the result.
but i dont know how to display it to the html.
if i do console.log(data.GroupSales[0].PICTURE);
i get the first PICTURE but i need do display it to the dom page forech.

Answer (score 0):

OK i found the answer:

```
$.each(data.GroupSales, function() {
        $('.hotel').append(
            '<tr><td>'
            + this.HOTELNAME
            + '</td><td>'
            + this.PICTURE +
            '</td></tr>'
        );
    });
```